# Handle missing arguments without knowing number of arguments

Tags: matlab

```matlab
function out = fn(a, b, z)
end
```

**Problem**: function whose argument count may change in the future, but the name of last argument stays same. Need to check whether last argument was passed in or not.

**Solution attempt**: `nargin` requires counting the number of arguments, and AFAIK, no easy way to get a function's number of input arguments. So, do

```matlab
try
    z
catch
    z = 'whatever';
```

Yet, it's clearly a hack and not ideal.

Is there a better way? Like `nmissingargin`? Assume all arguments are positional (but this is flexible).

**Note**: I'm aware of `fn(a, b, C)` ... `arguments a; b; C.z = 'whatever'` - too much code.

Comment: I would suggest: embrace the `arguments` block. It will make your code better. It will make it easier for you to write the preconditions for your function. It will make it easy to add default values. It will make it easy to add name-value pairs if you wish. There are some constraints - and those help you avoid non-idiomatic function prototypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @CrisLuengo -- use [exist](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html):

```matlab
function out = fn(a, b, z)
    if ~exist('z', 'var')
        z = 'whatever';
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing you can do is use the `varargin` variable as one of your arguments. This variable must be the last parameter in your functions, but otherwise does what you need it to.

Additionally, your function call will have `nargin`, which will give you the number of arguments passed into your function.

Per the documentation of [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) on this keyword:

```
function acceptVariableNumInputs(varargin)
    disp("Number of input arguments: " + nargin)
    celldisp(varargin)
end
```

Calling this function as follows:

```
acceptVariableNumInputs(ones(3),'some text',pi)
```

will achieve the following output:

```
Number of input arguments: 3
 
varargin{1} =
 
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1

 
 
varargin{2} =
 
some text
 
 
varargin{3} =
 
    3.1416
```

Comment: I'll consider it, though only the first paragraph's use may be acceptable - collapsing everything into `varargin` isn't desired.

Comment: Eh, it's something. Adds other handling code to ensure usage equivalence and not exceeding arg count. Keeping question open for other approaches.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on avoiding `arguments` blocks, you can still use `nargin` twice, like so:

```matlab
function out = foo(a, b, z)
    if nargin < nargin(str2func(mfilename))
        z = 'whatever'
    end
    out = {a, b, z};
end
```

This uses the [2nd syntax of `nargin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html#d126e1051759). (It's still pretty gross. `arguments` is better.)

Comment: That's a neat way to get number of arguments, assuming one function per file.

Comment: That could be `nargin(@foo)` for a local function.

Comment: Note that the `nargin(@foo)` approach fails if you start using `varargin` or whatever.